# Navigate to next div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried many thigs to navigate to next div element I'm using Mousetrap for key listener and checking if there is selected item then I'm trying to find the next div but seems like can't find anything any ideas?

HTML (There are many of this div item):

```
<div class="item">
<a href="#">
    <div class="item-flip">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
            <div class="item-details">
                <div class="item-details-inner">
                    <div class="down-details">
                    <div class="rating" data-content="9.5">
                    <i class="icon icon-star"></i>9.5
                    </div>
                    <span class="year">2011</span>
                    <span>Go</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Mousetrap.bind("right", function() {
    if($('.item-flip selected').length){
        var current = $('.item-flip selected');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        var el = current.next();
        el.addClass('selected');
    }
    else{
        $('.item-flip').first().addClass('selected')
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('.item-flip selected')` is incorrect and will return an empty array. --- Instead use `$('.item-flip .selected')`, notice the dot before "selected" to indicate a css class.

Comment: I tryed it and before same...return empty

Comment: Of course they'll be empty. As in your HTML there isn't an element with the classes of `.item-flip` and `.selected`. In your `else` block, you select the element which doesn't exist (as the `$('.item-flip selected').length` will be 0).

Comment: Yeah if there is not, is creating a selected element. The problem is that can't get next element. If else is working correct. The next returns empty and can't change selected element.
Got any solution?
Thanks for your time

Comment: `$('.item-flip selected')` will return `[]`. Making if statement resolve to false, `current` will be `[]`, making `current.next()` equal `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried how to figure out a solution, in the following my snippet the code.

The points of interest are:

- To select an element with two classes you need to change from `$('.item-flip selected')`  to `$('.item-flip.selected')`
- To get next element you need to find the clossest div father and then search for the item-flip div. So from `var el = current.next();` you need to change to: `var el = current.closest('.item').next().find('.item-flip');`

```js
$(function () {
  Mousetrap.bind("right", function(e) {
    if($('.item-flip.selected').length){
      var current = $('.item-flip.selected');
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      var el = current.closest('.item').next().find('.item-flip');
      el.addClass('selected');
    }
    else{
      $('.item-flip').first().addClass('selected')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/master/mousetrap.js"></script>

<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="item-flip">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <div class="item-details">
                <div class="item-details-inner">
                    <div class="down-details">
                        <div class="rating" data-content="9.5">
                            <i class="icon icon-star"></i>9.5
                        </div>
                        <span class="year">2011</span>
                        <span>Go</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="item-flip">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <div class="item-details">
                <div class="item-details-inner">
                    <div class="down-details">
                        <div class="rating" data-content="9.5">
                            <i class="icon icon-star"></i>9.5
                        </div>
                        <span class="year">2011</span>
                        <span>Go</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="item-flip">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <div class="item-details">
                <div class="item-details-inner">
                    <div class="down-details">
                        <div class="rating" data-content="9.5">
                            <i class="icon icon-star"></i>9.5
                        </div>
                        <span class="year">2011</span>
                        <span>Go</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why OP was wrong? --- Giving them the answer without a reason means the OP will keep making the same mistakes.

Comment: I saw the problem as I said couldn't find next element so must use a better find next method.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Answer updated! Thanks so much. I hope this time the answer is more clear.